# How to use windows cmd commands in flutter code?

Tags: android, flutter

I need to start an exe on Windows from a flutter app build for Windows.

[image]

In the app, when "Avvia SedisRemoteController" is pressed, an exe installed on Windows should run.

Anyone knows how to do it with the code? The command for windows cmd is simply

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Sedis Remote Controller\SedisRemoteController.exe"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I founded a workaround: using

https://pub.dev/packages/open_file/example

Adding this

```
OpenFile.open("C:/Program Files (x86)/Sedis Remote Controller/SedisRemoteController.exe");
```